# Windows Azure Powershell Deployment Error - "The remote server returned an unexpected response"

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-deployment

I'm following the latest February 2011 Azure Training Kit example.

I've successfully deployed using

```
New-Deployment -serviceName xxxxmytodo99 
                   -subscriptionId cxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx 
                   -certificate (get-item cert:\CurrentUser\MY\xxxxxxxxxxxx)
                   -slot staging 
                   -package MyTodo.cspkg
                   -configuration ServiceConfiguration.cscfg 
                   -label "v2.0" 
                   -storageServiceName xxxxmytodo99
```

Then running the next step -

```
Get-HostedService -serviceName xxxxmytodo99
                  -subscriptionId cxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx 
                  -certificate (get-item cert:\CurrentUser\MY\xxxxxxxxxxxx) 
    | Get-Deployment staging 
    | Set-Deployment -package MyTodo.cspkg 
                     -configuration ServiceConfiguration.cscfg 
                     -label "v2.1" 
    | Get-OperationStatus -WaitToComplete
```

Gives this error.

```
Set-Deployment : The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:232
+ Get-HostedService -serviceName xxxxmytodo99 -subscriptionId cxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  -certificate (get-item cert:\CurrentUser\MY\xxxxxxxxxxxx) | Get-Deployment staging | Set-Deployment <<<<  -package MyTodo.cspkg -configuration ServiceConfiguration.cscfg -label "v2.2" | Get-OperationStatus -WaitToComplete
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-Deployment], ProtocolException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Samples.AzureManagementTools.PowerShell.HostedServices.SetDeploymentCommand
```

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Found [this link](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/azurecmdlets/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=2742) detailing same issue that doesn't have a resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example gives this information

> **Important**: The Set-Deployment cmdlet
>   assumes that the compute service and
>   storage service names are the same. If
>   this is not the case, specify an
>   additional parameter
>   -StorageServicename ,
>   replacing the placeholder with the
>   name of the storage service name.

My storage service name does have the same name as the compute service, but adding that param made it work,

ie.

```
Get-HostedService -serviceName xxxxmytodo99 
                  -subscriptionId cxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx 
                  -certificate (get-item cert:\CurrentUser\MY\xxxxxxxxxxxx) 
        | Get-Deployment staging
        | Set-Deployment -package MyTodo.cspkg 
                         -configuration ServiceConfiguration.cscfg 
                         -storageServiceName xxxxmytodo99 
                         -label "v2.2" 
    | Get-OperationStatus -WaitToComplete
```